# Prepend/Append Makefile to a Qt generated Makefile

Tags: qt, qt4, makefile, qmake

I have a building environment where I add some prepending and appending lines to each Makefile generated.

It would be nice if I could put this lines into the qmake generated file via my project file (`.pro`).

Of cause I can do this via some easy shell scripting but it would be much nicer to do it from inside of the project file. Is there any qmake command to use?

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Example:

```
include $(ROOT)/prepend.mk

$(LIB):$(OBJ)
  @echo ...

include $(ROOT)/append.mk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Customizing Makefile Output](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qmake-environment-reference.html#customizing)

**.pro** file:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += extra_target
extra_target.commands = @echo Hello, World
```

Run **qmake**.

Run **make extra_target:**

> Hello, World

See the [documentation](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qmake-environment-reference.html#customizing) for additional options.

Comment: Yes this was what I was looking for...or actually already did. I was though trying to do this without running an extra 'make target'. Of cause this is the way of doing it. Thanx!